# Finding the limit as $x$ tends to $0^{+}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, self-learning

> Question: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} x \ \tan(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)$$

My Work:

To begin with I re-arranged the the question to the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{\tan(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Then applying *L'Hospital's rule* I got the following:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{\sec ^{2}(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)}{\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$$ which I rearranged to
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{x^{2}}{\cos ^{2}(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}$$
Applying *L'Hospital's rule* again I got the following:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{2x}{(-2)(-1))\cos(\frac{\pi }{2}-x)\sin(\frac{\pi }{2}-x) )} \ = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{2x}{\sin(\pi-2x) )}$$

Above I used the property $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x) \ \cos(x) $

And then applying *L'Hospital's rule* for the final time I got the following:
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{-1}{\cos(\pi-2x) )} = 1$$

Is my answer and method correct?

Comment: You forgot a minus sign while differentiating $\frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @LalitTolani I actually cancelled it out with the $(-1)$ that will be generated when differentiating the value within the $\tan$ function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method looks fine to me. However you need not apply L'Hospital's rule more than once because :

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x^2}{\cos^2(\pi/2 -x)} = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)} =  \lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \frac{x}{\sin x}\right)^2 = 1 $$

using $\cos(\pi/2 - x) = \sin(x)$ and the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$

As Jaap Scherphuis said in comments, we need not apply L Hospital's rule as $x \tan(\pi/2 - x) = \cos(x) \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \to 1$ as $x \to 0$ using the rules of limits.

Comment: This method is way more easier and will save me a lot of time. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Actually you don't even have to apply it the first time: $x \ \tan(\frac{\pi }{2}-x) = x\frac{1}{\tan x} = \frac{x}{\sin x} \cos{x} \rightarrow 1\cdot1$.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis Correct; I did not notice it, I have added it in the answer. Thank you.